# Ошибка при выводе представления

Tags: php, laravel

При выводе представления типа

```
return view('helpers.star_rating', ['name' => $name]);
```

вылазит такая ошибка

```
Uncaught Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory] is not instantiable.
```

Получается Ларавел не может создать фабрику. В чем тут может быть проблема?

Comment: нужно больше сорцов

Comment: https://github.com/illuminate/container/blob/master/Container.php#L754 Похоже, где то, вы переедаете не объект а интерфейс в данную функцию.  Что бы понять что не так, скинте код всего контроллера.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте отделить передаваемые параметры подобным образом

```
return view('helpers.star_rating')->with('name', $name);
```

Comment: Konstantin Soroka это не имеет никакого значения, и я так тоже делал

Comment: ArcherGodson каких именно?